# Was "America's ass" actually played by Chris Evans'?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, avengers-endgame, cgi

In *Avenger's Endgame*,

> there is a gag about Cap's buttocks being "America's ass".

Specifically,

> After the Cap-on-Cap battle in 2012 New York, past Cap is passed out on the floor, and future Cap (seeing his rear from third-person perspective for the first time) remarks,  "It really is America's ass."

Given that there is a wide shot of both of them together, was this rear end played by Chris Evans' through compositing?   Or was there a body double for this shot?   Is the object of the discussion improved with either prosthetic or digital enhancement?

Comment: Listen downvoters.  I get that you can think this is lurid.   But if the film is going to make jokes about something, I think it's fair game to inquire about how the supposed super-butt was accomplished.

Comment: Why would you imagine they'd need a double? It wasn't a pornographic film.

Comment: And it's also fair game to downvote questions asking about said joke. Your wording here is only more likely to turn people against you than get them on your side.

Comment: @Adamant: actors use body doubles for a variety of things. For example, it is the legs of Julia Roberts' body double on the poster of *Pretty Woman*.

Answer (score 17):

I don't know if this is definite, but McFeely (one of the writers) basically said that it's Evans:

> It’s a little meta. Chris Evans has never been comfortable with that outfit from the first “Avengers” movie. And so in the rearview mirror, it’s a little way to wink at how that was then and this is now. And then it sort of just built from there. By the time we got to the fight scene where he defeated himself, his butt is on the ground and was just sitting there for a callback.

[Source](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment/movies/la-et-mn-avengers-endgame-writers-markus-mcfeely-20190504-story.html)

**Update**

According to [second unit director Samuel Hargrave](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1092087/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr105), the butt is Evans':

> Hargrave says that although he and his brother, second unit director
>   Samuel Hargrave, stood in to help shoot the action sequence (as
>   younger and older Cap, respectively), the fanny shown off in that
>   scene belongs to Evans.
>
> "That was all him," Hargrave confirms.

and according to [Evans' stunt double](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm5045679/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr1541), it seems no prosthetics were used:

> It's "all natural," his stunt double Daniel Hargrave tells USA TODAY.
>   "I have to focus on (doing) a lot of squats" while working with him.
>   "He's got a nice butt."

[Source](https://www.usatoday.com/story/life/entertainthis/2019/05/03/avengers-endgame-captain-america-chris-evans-butt-appreciation/3652686002/)

Comment: "fanny" ... wow. In British English that word means something very different :-/

Comment: @Randal'Thor the first time I heard the phrase "fanny pack" my mind just sprinted off trying to figure out WTF one of those could possibly be or even if it was a verb or a noun

Comment: @GordonBennett: Funny thing is, it works on both sides of the pond depending on if you wear it in the front or the back.